# Creating a new variable with For loop in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have a data set in R. Variable `x` is binary (0 or 1), and I need to create a new variable, `y`, such that if `x[i]` is `0` then `y[i]` is `0`, but if `x[i]` is `1`, then `y[i]=1`, `y[i+1]=1`, and `y[i+2]=1`. This is what I have done, but it's not working for some reason. Any help is appreciated.

```
for (i in 1:length(mydata$x) ) {    
  if(mydata$x==1) {
    mydata$y[i] <- 1
    mydata$y[i+1] <- 1
    mydata$y[i+2] <- 1
  } else {
    mydata$y[i] <- 0
  }    
}
```

Here is an example of the data:

```
x   y
0   0
0   0
0   0
1   1
0   1
0   1
0   0
0   0
1   1 # this is the last row, so '1' should only be added once.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to edited question:**

First, initialize `y` to all zeros, and then check `x` only for ones (do nothing if you find a zero):

```
mydata$y <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata))
  if(mydata$x[i] == 1)
    mydata$y[i:min((i+2),nrow(mydata))] <- 1
```

**Answer to old question:**

You are not indexing `mydata$x` in the `if` condition. Change to this:

```
for (i in 1:length(mydata$x) ) {
  if(mydata$x[i] == 1) { # here
    mydata$y[i] <- 1
    mydata$y[i+1] <- 1
    mydata$y[i+2] <- 1
  } else {
    mydata$y[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Note that if `x[i]==1` and `x[i+1]==0`, then you'll do `y[i+1]<-1` and then `y[i+1]<-0`, changing what you did when checking `x[i]==1`. Also, if the last or second to last value in `x` is `1`, you'll be trying to set a value in `y` beyond its limits when doing `y[i+1]<-1` and `y[i+2]<-1`, which will give you an error. I doubt this is what you really want.

Example:

```
mydata <- structure(list(x = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
            y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("x", 
            "y"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

You'll get:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "y", value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  : 
>     replacement has 11 rows, data has 10

You can try fixing with:

```
for (i in 1:length(mydata$x) ) {
  if(mydata$x[i] == 1) {
    mydata$y[i:min((i+2),nrow(mydata))] <- 1
  } else {
    mydata$y[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran the code, but the variable y is identical to the variable x. i think the resean behind this is that everytime x=0, then y=0. do you know how to adjust the code? Thanks again!

Comment: Your problem is not clear enough, you may want to add a sample dataset and desired outcome

Comment: As @vaettchen said, please give us an example of what you want to do, exactly

Answer (score 2):

#### Vectorized approach

Here it is as a one-liner.  Below is a breakdown of the approach

```
y <- as.numeric(seq_along(x) %in% outer(which(!!x), 0:2, "+"))
```

---

---

if you have an index of the values of `x` which are `1`, you simply add `0:2` to each element of those index and you get the index to `y` which should be `1`

```
y <- rep(0, length(x))

inds <- which(x==1)

## add c(0, 1, 2) to each element of inds
inds <- outer(inds, 0:2, "+")

## make it into a vector
inds <- unique(as.vector(inds))

y[inds] <- 1
```